# Best way to insert an array element inside an array of arrays

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp-2.1

I'm trying to insert an array element  which contains an `id` for relational data inside an array save multiple records in `CakePHP`.

This is how the array appears:

```
[Venue] => Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [name] => Great mansion
        [where] => New York
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [name] => Diamond palace
        [where] => London
    )
    [2] => Array (
        [name] => Palazzo Falcone
        [where] => Bologna
    )
)
```

I would like to add the `architect_id` to every element of the array, so:

```
[Venue] => Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [name] => Great mansion
        [where] => New York
        [architect_id] => 33
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [name] => Diamond palace
        [where] => London
        [architect_id] => 33
    )
    [2] => Array (
        [name] => Palazzo Falcone
        [where] => Bologna
        [architect_id] => 33
    )
)
```

I'm not sure if what I've wrote is optimized or it can be improved:

```
$tot = count($this->request->data['Venue']);

for ($i = 0; $i < $tot; $i ++) {
    $this->request->data['Venue'][$i]['architect_id'] = $this->Architect->id;
}

$this->Venue->saveAll($this->request->data['Venue']);
```

The code works but is this a good way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is fine so far.

```
foreach ($this->request->data['Venue'] as &$venue) {
  $venue['architect_id'] = $this->Architect->id;
}
```

Should work too. Decide yourself, which one you find more readable.